# Only void function can be called with the "new" keyword

Tags: javascript, typescript, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to use the Foundation's Reveal plugin in my Typescript code in following way (altered for readability):

```
var popup = new Foundation.Reveal($('#element'));
```

and I'm getting following error during compilation (in the end it does compile and work anyway):

```
TS2350: Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword.
```

How should I write it then?

[Typescript Playground - code illustrating the problem](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20namespace%20FoundationSites%20%7B%0D%0A%09interface%20Reveal%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20open()%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20toggle()%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20close()%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20destroy()%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20IRevealOptions%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20animationIn%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20animationOut%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20showDelay%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20hideDelay%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20closeOnClick%3F%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20closeOnEsc%3F%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20multipleOpened%3F%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vOffset%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20hOffset%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fullScreen%3F%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20btmOffsetPct%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20overlay%3F%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20resetOnClose%3F%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09interface%20FoundationSitesStatic%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Reveal(element%3AObject%2C%20options%3F%3AIRevealOptions)%3A%20Reveal%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20var%20Foundation%3AFoundationSites.FoundationSitesStatic%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20module%20%22Foundation%22%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20%3D%20Foundation%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20popup%20%3D%20new%20Foundation.Reveal(%24(%27%23element%27))%3B)

Comment: I think you are messing things up. Why would you want to do a new if Reveal is a function that returns an object?

Comment: It's the only way I made it work so far...

Comment: Based on the code in playground you should do: `var popup = Foundation.Reveal($('#element'))` (that is, without the `new`)

Answer (score 10):

I find a way to shut the typescript compiler up, but this will give up the type check(Do it with your caution).

```
var popup = new (Foundation.Reveal as any)($('#element'));
```

---

More example:

```
function User2(name) {
    if (this instanceof User2) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    else {
        return new (User2 as any)(name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on the interface:

```
interface FoundationSitesStatic {
    Reveal(element:Object, options?:IRevealOptions): Reveal;
}
```

you cannot  call it with the `new` operator (used to call a constructor).

So fix:

```
var popup = Foundation.Reveal($('#element'));
```

Comment: Yup, it does compile, but it doesn't work :) That's why I asked this question ;)

Comment: I think it is valid JavaScript, but invalid in TypeScript. And that confuses me too, like @Wiktor, because they say that TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript. But now it seems that it actually doesn't.

Comment: Yes, the problem with this is... I have code that is correct when I call it with the new operator, and has a bug when I don't. So I really just need a way to shut the typescript compiler up

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this:

```js
interface FoundationSitesStatic {
    Reveal: new (element: Object, options?: IRevealOptions) => Reveal;
}
```

Which lets you do what works without TypeScript errors and without sacrificing type safety!

```js
const popup = new Foundation.Reveal($('#element'));
```